# In word, is it possible to add nested lists with different bullet styles for different subsections

Tags: ms-word, openxml

In nested lists in word. Is it possible to have different bullet styles for different sublists. Like 1->1.1,1.2 and 2->a,b?

tried in word to do the same and was unable to acheive it. Tried modifying corresponding openxml elements but still was not working.

Comment: This is really a Word question.  Answer is no, since a list level override applies to the whole list .  You could simulate it by using different lists (in your example, different lists for 1 and 2), and setting the startat values (eg 1, 2), but your code would need to figure those values out.

Comment: Tried the following
**1)** For 1.1 and 1.2 wrote a new num with same abstract num as previous and wrote a lvlOverride for lvl1 with %1.%2 as the lvlText.                
**2)** Similarly for a,b wrote a new num with a new lvlOverride at lvl1 with lvltext as %2 and lowerLetter as numberFormat.
Visually I have acheived what I wanted but I don't know if all the properties of lists work fine with what I have done.